# Setting access control for comments (allow comments = approved instead of all) using youtube Api V3

Tags: api, youtube

We are using youtube api v3 to upload video from our content management application to youtube. Everything works as expected. But in advanced settings there are options for comments in UI. With in comments there is an dropdown for Allow comment. By default it is setting to all. How can we set to approved using youtube v3 api. Using v3 api can we do it at all? If not any chance that might be added in V3 and how soon it will be? How can do it in v2 if we can't in v3? Appreciate you help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I too don't how to update it through V3 but we can do it in V2. In access controls you can find "comment" parameter. For approved comments i think you need to set it as "moderated".

[image]